# Script cannot find existing file

Tags: linux, shell, sas

I am trying to run a script named sassetup in folder /usr/local/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4 on a linux machine. The first two lines of the script are as follows.

```
eval 'exec `dirname $0`/perl/bin/perl5 -U $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if $running_under_some_shell;
```

I get an error message saying

```
./sassetup: line 1: /usr/local/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/perl/bin/perl5: No such file or directory
```

The file in the error message actually exists because the command below

```
ls -lt /usr/local/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/perl/bin/perl5
```

outputs

```
-rwxr-xr-x 3 5402 users 790559 Jan 24  2002 /usr/local/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/perl/bin/perl5
```

The output of

```
uname -a
```

is

```
Linux 4.15.0-112-generic 16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The output of

```
file /usr/local/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/perl/bin/perl5
```

is

```
/usr/local/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/perl/bin/perl5: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped
```

The file /lib/ld-linux.so.2 does not exist. Two similar files, /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 and /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, exist.

The output of adding LD_DEBUG=all before the command when running is as follows.

```
     14403: 
 14403: file=/lib/$LIB/liblsp.so [0];  needed by sh [0]
 14403: file=/lib/$LIB/liblsp.so [0];  generating link map
 14403:   dynamic: 0x00007fc46f12fdf0  base: 0x00007fc46ef2c000   size: 0x0000000000204348
 14403:     entry: 0x00007fc46ef2d450  phdr: 0x00007fc46ef2c040  phnum:                  7
 14403: 
 14403: 
 14403: file=libtinfo.so.5 [0];  needed by sh [0]
 14403: find library=libtinfo.so.5 [0]; searching
 14403:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
 14403:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5
 14403: 
 14403: file=libtinfo.so.5 [0];  generating link map
 14403:   dynamic: 0x00007fc46ef2ad08  base: 0x00007fc46ed03000   size: 0x0000000000228cc0
 14403:     entry: 0x00007fc46ed0f870  phdr: 0x00007fc46ed03040  phnum:                  7
 14403: 
 14403: 
 14403: file=libdl.so.2 [0];  needed by sh [0]
 14403: find library=libdl.so.2 [0]; searching
 14403:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
 14403:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
 14403: 
 14403: file=libdl.so.2 [0];  generating link map
 14403:   dynamic: 0x00007fc46ed01d88  base: 0x00007fc46eaff000   size: 0x00000000002030f0
 14403:     entry: 0x00007fc46eaffda0  phdr: 0x00007fc46eaff040  phnum:                  7
 14403: 
 14403: 
 14403: file=libc.so.6 [0];  needed by sh [0]
 14403: find library=libc.so.6 [0]; searching
 14403:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
 14403:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 14403: 
 14403: file=libc.so.6 [0];  generating link map
 14403:   dynamic: 0x00007fc46eaf8ba0  base: 0x00007fc46e735000   size: 0x00000000003c99a0
 14403:     entry: 0x00007fc46e755960  phdr: 0x00007fc46e735040  phnum:                 10
 14403: 
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.2.5' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 [0] required by file sh [0]
 14403: checking for version `NCURSES_TINFO_5.0.19991023' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0] required by file sh [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.11' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file sh [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.14' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file sh [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.8' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file sh [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.15' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file sh [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.4' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file sh [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.3.4' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file sh [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.3' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file sh [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.2.5' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file sh [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.2.5' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 [0] required by file /lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsp.so [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.4' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file /lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsp.so [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.2.5' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file /lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsp.so [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.3' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.14' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.16' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.4' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.3.4' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.2.5' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_PRIVATE' in file /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0] required by file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_PRIVATE' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.2.5' in file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] required by file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_2.3' in file /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0] required by file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]
 14403: checking for version `GLIBC_PRIVATE' in file /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0] required by file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]
 14403: 
 14403: Initial object scopes
 14403: object=sh [0]
 14403:  scope 0: sh /lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsp.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
 14403: 
 14403: object=linux-vdso.so.1 [0]
 14403:  scope 0: sh /lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsp.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
 14403:  scope 1: linux-vdso.so.1
 14403: 
 14403: object=/lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsp.so [0]
 14403:  scope 0: sh /lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsp.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
 14403: 
 14403: object=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0]
 14403:  scope 0: sh /lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsp.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
 14403: 
 14403: object=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 [0]
 14403:  scope 0: sh /lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsp.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
 14403: 
 14403: object=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]
 14403:  scope 0: sh /lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsp.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
 14403: 
 14403: object=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
 14403:  no scope
 14403: 
 14403: 
 14403: relocation processing: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (lazy)
 14403: symbol=_res;  lookup in file=sh [0]
 14403: symbol=_res;  lookup in file=/lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsp.so [0]
 14403: symbol=_res;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0]
 14403: symbol=_res;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 [0]
 14403: symbol=_res;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]
 14403: binding file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_res' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 14403: symbol=stderr;  lookup in file=sh [0]
 14403: binding file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] to sh [0]: normal symbol `stderr' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 14403: symbol=error_one_per_line;  lookup in file=sh [0]
 14403: symbol=error_one_per_line;  lookup in file=/lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsp.so [0]
 14403: symbol=error_one_per_line;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0]
 14403: symbol=error_one_per_line;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 [0]
 14403: symbol=error_one_per_line;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]
 14403: binding file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `error_one_per_line' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
 14403: symbol=__malloc_initialize_hook;  lookup in file=sh [0]
 14403: symbol=__malloc_initialize_hook;  lookup in file=/lib/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblsp.so [0]
 14403: symbol=__malloc_initialize_hook;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0]
 14403: symbol=__malloc_initialize_hook;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 [0]
 14403: symbol=__malloc_initialize_hook;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]
 14403: binding file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `__malloc_initialize_hook' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
```

How do I make sure that the script finds this file?

Comment: What architecture are running on? Could you post the output of `file /usr/local/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/perl/bin/perl5` and `uname -a`? The `No such file or directory` may be an errno from linker. On other note - what is the point of that `eval 'exec` line? Why `eval`? Why is there an `if` after `exec`?

Comment: the only time I can remember seeing this kind of behaviour is on hosts with NFS mounts, are you running the ls -lt on the same host?

Comment: The output of file /usr/local/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/perl/bin/perl5 and uname -a are posted in the question. I don't know the point of the eval 'exec line because this script was written by someone else. I don't know why eval is needed. I don't know why there is if after exec. @KamilCuk

Comment: I am running the ls -lt command on the same host. But, I kind of understand why you mean, @Vorsprung. I find this link, https://superuser.com/questions/324990/bash-says-file-does-not-exist-but-it-does, which might be related. I cannot, however, understand the solution that this link provides.

Comment: `x86_64` and `ELF 32-bit LSB` Do you have `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` file? Och, try doing `LD_DEBUG=ALL the_command` before running, if it's the linker it could shed some light.

Comment: The file /lib/ld-linux.so.2 does not exist. Two similar files, /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 and /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, exist. @KamilCuk

Comment: The output of adding LD_DEBUG=all before the command when running is added in the question post. @KamilCuk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Linux 4.15.0-112-generic 16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux

Your system is 64-bit.

> /usr/local/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/perl/bin/perl5: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped

The application is 32-bit.

> The file /lib/ld-linux.so.2 does not exist

You have to install the 32-bit versions of libraries to run 32-bit applications under 64-bit. Install glibc compiled for 32-bit. On my archlinux the package is called `lib32-glibc`.